# PHP MySQLi Photo single page

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, photo

I have made a photo gallery, which shows photos from MySQLi database, but when I click on the link on each photo, it must go to a single page that only shows that photo.

**Index.php**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM images");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $id = $row['id'];     
   $image = $row['image'];
   echo "<td><a href='single.php?id=$id'><img src='$image'></a></td>";
}
```

**Single.php**

```
$id = $row['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id='$id'");
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  $image = $row['image'];
  echo "<img src='$image'>";
}
```

Comment: `?id` is a GET array method; you're not using one. Look at your HTML source also; what does it reveal?

Answer (score 0):

**Single.php** change first line to

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Comment: Also, consider switching over to prepared sql statements, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections